# Slow Visual Studio, related to SQMClient?

Tags: visual-studio, process-monitor

Visual Studio started working slower than usual, and after checking for add-ons and doing a repair, it's just as slow. I used process monitor to check what was going on, and found that a lot of stuff is going on related to SQMClient, which - as far as I understand, is part of Microsoft's customer feedback program. I'm not participating in the program (I've double checked). Still - process monitor tells me that VS does a lot of stuff related to SQMClient:

- RegQueryKey   HKLM    SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
- RegOpenKey    HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SQMClient   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
- RegSetInfoKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient   SUCCESS KeySetInformationClass: KeySetHandleTagsInformation, Length: 0
- RegQueryValue HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient\UploadDisableFlag NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
- RegCloseKey   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient   SUCCESS

It keeps repeating this over and over. Do any of you know why VS might do this, and if this is the reason behind the slow behavior?

Comment: Also check whether you have a virus scanner configured for scan-on-read.  I recall a similar problem with VS2008 where VS was reading the snippets XML file every second or two (for what reason I don't know) and the virus scanner was busy 100% of the time virus scanning that file.  Caused a noticeable delay to the point that it took about 5 seconds between the time you press a key on keyboard and the character appears in the editor window.

Comment: Tried that, but it seems my company has locked parts of the virus scanner configuration... I think it has to be something else doing this, as it just happened. Weird. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Is one or more of your CPU's busy all of the time?  If so, you can ask someone from your IT department to login and they should be able to click "Show all processes for all users" and see if your virus scanner is using lots of CPU.  In fact, if you are able to run process monitor, you may already have the necessary permission to view this type of CPU usage info yourself.  Another option would be to ask them to disable your virus scanner for 30 minutes or so and see if the problem goes away.  Have had many problems with VS & McAfee interacting in nasty ways, that's why I bring it up.

Answer (score 12):

This problem may happen if there is a number of SQM reports, saved in the user profile. When unable to connect to internet Visual Studio stores SQM files in `%userhome%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\<vs_version>\SQM`. The number of files grows continuously and it can get to many thousands. When this directory is cleaned or removed, Visual Studio sped up significantly.

Comment: Thanks. I had over 19000 sqm files, and removing them improved VS startup time, and I haven't seen any lags like I was seeing before.