# Visual Studio 2017-2019 works extremely slow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I work on c++ project on VS, and a lot of operations that were fast now super slow. Saving a file could take minutes, intelISense may take forever to show hints, navigating functions takes long time. I tried to reinstall VS 2017, but behavior havent changed. I tried to move to VS 2019, but observe same things. I have 6700k, 32gb ram, Windows 10 with latest updates, both VS installed on NVME M2 drive(around 3000 mb/s write/read), so my PC rather fast. Any ideas how I can solve it? Development sometimes feels unbearable.

[image]

EDIT: So, I deleted everything that was remotely close to Visual Studio (VS15-17-19, build tools, Nsight, CUDA integration) and installed clean VS19 installation only with v142 tools for C++. So far(few hours in) it works fine. I dont know what was the problem, but I hope it fixed it. Will report later if lags will return.

Comment: Do you have any extensions that are running?  Is there an anti-virus?  Long time ago I has to use Norton AntiVirus and could not use VS while it was doing its daily scan.

Comment: No, I dont. I checked extensions, but I installed only QT

Comment: Are any other applications having the same issue?  Do other developers working on the same project's having similar issues?

Comment: What happens if you uninstall QT?  or before you install it on a new VS?

Comment: Could this be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957158/qt-creator-debug-mode-is-really-slow ?

Comment: No other applications work fast. I tried different projects, same issue. I guess I will try to uninstall QT as I will not need it for at least a month, and will see how studio will behave.

Comment: Have you contacted the vendor? What did you change? Does it show on other systems as well? Does it show when using a different user account?

Comment: Does you %APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\15.0\SQM folder contain thousand of files? If yes [slow visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643535/slow-visual-studio-related-to-sqmclient) might help.